# How to manipulate spark dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is a spark_df with many duplicates as follows:

```
Name       Cost
Alicja     5
Alicja     10
Alicja     7
Piotr      2
Piotr      8
Jon        5
```

Now I want to transform this spark_df as follows:

```
Name       min_Cost  max _cost
Alicja     5            10
Piotr      2            8
Jon        5            5
```

I know this in pandas. But I am trying to learn spark so that I can implement it into big data. If  anyone can help that will be great.

Answer (score 3):

aggregate `min` and `max` for each `Name` with `groupby`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupby('Name').agg(
  f.min('Cost').alias('min_cost'), 
  f.max('Cost').alias('max_cost')
).show()
+------+--------+--------+
|  Name|min_cost|max_cost|
+------+--------+--------+
| Piotr|       2|       8|
|Alicja|       5|      10|
|   Jon|       5|       5|
+------+--------+--------+
```